# Maildir is much larger than expected

Tags: emacs, maildir, mu

I'm retrieving my email using `offlineimap` to a local maildir which I am indexing with `mu` (reading/writing is done using `mu4e` in `emacs`).

After loading all emails from the server my Maildir folder is about 1.1GB in size. However, the very same account takes much less space when downloaded with thunderbird (less than 500Mb).

I assume that the reduction in disk space is due to some compression so my question is

> How can I reduce the disk usage of my Maildir setup without losing email history?

Comment: How about removing the attachments from the cache for the largest e-mails?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because there are messages that are contained in multiple imap folders and are thus getting duplicated.  For example, in Gmail, the "[Gmail]/All Mail" and some other folders are usually redunant.  I use

```
[Repository Gmail-Remote]
  folderfilter = lambda foldername: foldername not in ['[Gmail]/All Mail', '[Gmail]/Important', '[Gmail]/Starred']
```

in .offlineimaprc to avoid this problem.  depending on what subset of folders contains all messages without much redundancy, you might need to do things differently.